# Enhance ASP.NET Web Forms project to support routing

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to have a routing similar to below for existing projects.

All of my current pages are like http://example.com/virtualDirectory/page1.aspx

Sample: http://localhost/EmployeeMgmt/Dashboard.aspx

Is it possible to setup a routing like,

http://localhost/EmployeeMgmt/customer1/Dashboard.aspx
http://localhost/EmployeeMgmt/customer2/Dashboard.aspx

where customer1 and customer2 are dynamic routing names (customer name) so that I can decide that page is belongs to which customer?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Can't you simply pass customer name as parameter to Dashboard.aspx? Example: http://localhost/EmployeeMgmt/Dashboard.aspx?customerName=customer1

Comment: Also read this articles - they should help: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#Anchor_2
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx

Comment: it's possible but in hardest way - like @Ashiv3r wrote - this is proper way https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: As far I remember, when you create a default asp.net Webforms project (not the empty one) you will have automatically the base elements needed to deal with routing. However I don't suggest you to create a project this way as it add a lot of more or less useful DLLs.

Comment: @Ashiv3r I can't the supply the customer name at this stage, since the project was huge and developing since many years. Only of my recommendation was having customer id/name as part of routing so that I can track customer at once place. If any other better recommendations please suggest.

Comment: @Ashiv3r the link which you have given https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#Anchor_2 have an example which I have already tried, but it deals the routing to only specific page "~/categoriespage.aspx". Is there any routing which is common to all the pages? (other than query string)

Comment: @SrinivasaRao have you tried "~/*.aspx" or "~/{*fullpath}" ? Not sure if it work, but it's a physical path to file, so maybe give it a try :)

Comment: @SrinivasaRao Also this article may help, because I'm not sure if I understand you right: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.routing.routecollection.mappageroute?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples

Comment: @Ashiv3r I tried both of these "~/*.aspx" or "~/{*fullpath}" and didn't work. Also had a look into routing from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.routing.routecollection.mappageroute?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples but they are still pointing to specific page. Exactly I was looking similar to "customer/{name}", "~/**.aspx" But the most of the example have specific page in second parameter. I still didn't understood whether it is possible in ASP.NET?

Comment: @SrinivasaRao what exactly do you want to achieve? Do you want to get access to different customers by navigating into different routes? Like:
http://localhost/EmployeeMgmt/customer1/Dashboard.aspx gives you access to customer1 in Dashboard.aspx ?
http://localhost/EmployeeMgmt/customer2/Dashboard.aspx gives you access to customer2 in Dashboard.aspx ?

Comment: @Ashiv3r Finally I figured out. "{name}/{pagename.aspx}", "~/{pagename.aspx}" this works well.

Comment: @SrinivasaRao Congrats, glad that articles showed you the way :)